# Create an npm Package for React Native with Swift Libraries

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-native-bridge, react-native-modules

In my React Native app, I've successfully implemented a functionality to select images from the gallery and perform image cropping using bridging/Native modules and to implement that I have used two Swift libraries:

- "Mantis": "~>2.14.1"
- "BSImagePicker": "~>3.1"
  I attempted to create an npm package, but unfortunately, I encountered challenges and was not able to succeed. Additionally, I couldn't find any existing npm library made with native modules or bridging.
  Am i trying to acheive the impossible??
  I would greatly appreciate any guidance or Help. Here is the Git repository of my npm package: https://github.com/NitishGarg76/ImagePickerAndCropper
  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you employed the React Native template provided by the following command?

```
npx create-react-native-library@latest react-native-awesome-module
```

This template comes equipped with all the necessary components for publishing. You only need to execute the npm release command.